# Diferencias entre continue y break en PHP

Tags: php

¿Que diferencias hay entre poner `break` o poner `continue` dentro de un bucle?

Sé que `break` interrumpe el bucle, pero `continue` no sé exactamente lo que hace.

¿Cuándo es necesario utilizar uno u otro? ¿Qué diferencias hay entre ellos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`break` y `continue` son dos de las sentencias más utilizadas en [php](/questions/tagged/php) para manipular el flujo de las iteraciones en las estructuras de control cíclicas, como por ejemplo: for, foreach, while, do-while o switch. Ambas cortan el ciclo actual pero con una importante diferencia:

- [**break**](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.break.php) finaliza la ejecución de la estructura control en curso.
- [**continue**](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.continue.php) finaliza la iteración actual de la estructura control y se inicia una nueva iteración.

A continuación te pongo unos ejemplos de funcionamiento, donde podrás ver la diferencia de forma más gráfica:

```
while ( $x) {             
    break;         ----- salta aquí ----┐
}
                  <---------------------┘

foreach( $items as $item ) {  <--------------------┐
    continue;                 --- vuelve aquí -----┘
}
```

Explicado en otras palabras, `continue` le dice a PHP que la iteración actual se ha acabado y debe empezar en la evaluación de la condición para la siguiente iteración. Por otra parte, `break` le dice a PHP que la evaluación de la estructura control actual ha terminado y que no siga haciendo iteraciones.

Toda esta información ha sido extraída de la siguiente página: [Diferencias entre break y continue en PHP](https://cybmeta.com/break-y-continue-en-php) en la que viene muy bien explicado y detallado.

Answer (score 6):

`continue` se utiliza dentro de las estructuras iterativas para saltar el resto de la iteración actual del bucle y continuar la ejecución en la evaluación de la condición, para luego comenzar la siguiente iteración.

Y `break` finaliza la ejecución de la estructura for, foreach, while, do-while o switch en curso.

Fuentes:

http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.continue.php

http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como se explica en [Diferencias entre break y continue en PHP](https://cybmeta.com/break-y-continue-en-php), de   Juan Padial:

> break y continue son dos de las sentencias más utilizadas en PHP para manipular el flujo de las iteraciones en las estructuras de control cíclicas (for, foreach, while, do-while o switch). Ambas cortan el ciclo actual pero con una importante diferencia:
>
> break finaliza la ejecución de la estructura control en curso.
>   continue finaliza la iteración actual de la estructura control y se inicia una nueva iteración.
>
> ```
> while ( $foo ) {   <--------------------┐
>     continue;      --- vuelve aquí -----┘
>     break;         ----- salta aquí ----┐
> }
>                   <---------------------┘
> ```
>
> Esto implica, básicamente que:
>
> En otras palabras, continue le dice a PHP que la iteración actual se ha acabado y debe empezar en la evaluación de la condición que abre la estructura de control. Por su parte, break le dice a PHP que la evaluación de la estructura control actual ha terminado y que no siga haciendo iteraciones.
>
> Si hacemos un simple test como este:
>
> ```
> $letters = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];
> foreach ( $letters as $letter) {
>     if( 'A' == $letter ) {
>         continue;
>         echo 'Esto nunca se imprimirá';
>     }
>     echo $letter;
> }
> ```
>
> Se imprimirá la cadena BC ya que cuándo $letter es igual a A la iteración no alcanza la sentencia echo $letter; sino que vuelve al principio del foreach.
>
> Por el contrario, si hacemos:
>
> ```
> $letters = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];
> foreach ( $letters as $letter) {
>     if( 'A' == $letter ) {
>         break;
>         echo 'Esto nunca se imprimirá';
>     }
>     echo $letter;
> }
> ```
>
> No se imprimirá nada ya que en la primera iteración, cuándo $letter es igual a A, se finaliza la ejecución de la estructura foreach y ninguno de los echo es alcanzado.
>
> Cuándo break o continue se utilizan en una estructura de control anidada en otra se puede especificar el número de estructuras a las que afectan. El número por omisión es 1 y afecta sólo a la estructura actual. Estas dos estructuras serían iguales:
>
> ```
> while ( $foo ) {
>     $items = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
>     foreach( $items as $item ) {  <--------------------┐
>         continue;                 --- vuelve aquí -----┘
>     }
> }
>
> // Esta estructura es igual a la anterior
> while ( $foo ) {
>     $items = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
>     foreach( $items as $item ) {  <--------------------┐
>         continue 1;               --- vuelve aquí -----┘
>     }
> }
>
> while ( $foo ) {                 <--------------------┐
>     $items = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
>     foreach( $items as $item ) {
>         continue 2;               --- vuelve aquí ----┘
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: [¿Cómo referir material a otros?](/help/referencing).

Comment: lo siento lo editare.

Comment: voto negativo. Esto no es citar, sino copiar. Lee con detenimiento el enlace [¿Cómo referir material a otros?](/help/referencing) y procede tal y como se describe allí. De lo contrario se están infringiendo las reglas del sitio.

Comment: Creo que no es necesario el voto negativo @fedorqui

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper ¿por qué?

Comment: Ha incluido todo lo que viene aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing en la respuesta @fedorqui

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper no veo ninguna [citación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).

Comment: Ha incluido este enlace: https://cybmeta.com/break-y-continue-en-php  @fedorqui

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper insisto, [¿Cómo referir material a otros?](/help/referencing) indica claramente: _asegúrate que realizas lo siguiente: 1. Incluir un enlace a la página original o respuesta. 2. Citar únicamente la parte relevante. 3. Incluir el nombre del autor original._

Comment: @fedorqui el enlace está al final de la respuesta

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper mira [mi edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/76870/revisions), en la que intento respetar los tres puntos antes descritos.

Comment: Tenias razón, todo aclarado. Mis disculpas @fedorqui